# XSD inheritance causes problems in Jersey/JAXB

Tags: jaxb, xsd, jersey

I have the following XSD file (contents shown):

```
<xs:element name="person" type="Person"/>
<xs:element name="child" type="Child"/>

<xs:complexType name="Person">
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
       <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:string"/>
       <xs:element name="fullname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Child">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Person">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="grade" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="school" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm able to marshal instances of the Child class and send them to a client browser using the Jersey REST API.

But when I try to do this for the Person class it no longer works. I get the error message:

```
A message body writer for Java class app.Person, and Java type class app.Person, and MIME media type application/xml was not found
```

By extending the Person schema type, am I somehow rendering it no longer a root-level element? When Child doesn't extend Person, it works fine.

Comment: What does your jersey service look like? What is the return type on your method annotated with `@GET`?

Comment: The return type is Person. The GET resource produces JSON/XML. It's identical to the other (working) resource whose return type is Child.

Comment: Are you leveraging a `ContextResolver` for the working case?